# Adding a popup/snippet/title on top of the marker in my custom OSM map

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I need to add a popup which displays city name (own description) on top of my added marker, below is my marker code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
private MapView osm;
osm = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    public void addMarker() {

            GeoPoint colombo = new GeoPoint(6.9271, 79.8612);

            Marker startMarker = new Marker(osm);
            startMarker.setPosition(colombo);
            osm.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
            startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startMarker.setTitle("title")` 
should do the job... you can manually show it by calling `showInfoWindow()` method on the startMarker.

If you want to have your own layout of the popup, you can subclass `InfoWindow`.